# Can't reinstall Rails, ruby not functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had issues, which I think had something to do with the `PATH` related to RVM.

I tried to reinstall all of my ruby related stuff. I trashed rubygems-2.1.7 and rakemaster. I tried uninstalling RVM, but it said to do some stuff manually, which I am not familiar. I uninstalled rails and ruby.

Now, I can't get them to work. I thought I installed Rails version 4, and it said I needed to upgrade my ruby from 1.9 to 2. I tried to do so through RVM, but either on Ruby or IRB, I get:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

Nevertheless, when I run `rvm install`, it says that version 2.0.0 is installed. so I don't understand what is not working. I am confused and could use some help on the best direction to go.

Comment: I've been told not to use RVM with rails. I don't know much about reinstalling that, but it is a good advice to avoid *VM when possible.

Comment: Why is that? I have mostly read things advising to use RVM, do you have any links to people saying why one shouldn't?

Comment: When you do `which ruby` & `which gem`, what path is it giving you?

Comment: I disagree with Alejandro... version managers are a must, be it RVM or  rbenv

Comment: RVM keeps things easy to install and so on, but there are some topics as stability by example. This link (of course for RHEL) shows how easy and simple is install RoR with software collection. http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/01/28/software-collections-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux/
Repo might be a cleaner, better idea if you can use it. Of course it depends of your compatibility with other apps.

Comment: @realchaseadams   '$ which ruby

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

$ which gem

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem'

Comment: sorry the formatting is bad

Comment: About my last comment, I can't edit it but instead of Repo i meant rpm